# Upper bound of integral $\int_0^b\frac{1}{x+2^x} dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Is it known a closed form of the integral:
$$\displaystyle\int_0^b\dfrac{1}{x+2^x} dx?$$
Using the Talenti inequality I found the following bound:
$$\displaystyle\int_0^b\dfrac{1}{x+2^x} dx\lt\ln\left(1-\dfrac{-1+e^{-b}}{\ln(2)}\right)$$
For $b\gt\gt1$ the difference between the integral and the logarithm in the right doesn't exceed 0.19
Is it known some better result? Obviously it is possible to evaluate numerically this integral.

Comment: Your problem is same as finding the antiderivative of $\frac1{x+2^x}$, which, I believe, is not elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use a simple Riemann-Integral to determine this upper bound.
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^b \frac{1}{x'+2^{x'}} dx'  =& \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+ b\, 2^{\frac{x}{b}}} dx\\
  \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+b\,2^{\frac{x}{b}}} dx <& \sum_{i=0}^N \frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{\frac{i}{N}+b\,2^{\frac{i}{Nb}}} = \sum_{i=0}^N \frac{1}{i+Nb\,  2^{\frac{i}{Nb}}}
\end{eqnarray}